# EJB Mapping of @OneToMany relationships with more than one key in mappedBy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, ejb-3.0

In my project, I want to use @OneToMany relationships with more than one key in mappedBy attribute.

In my project, I have **IncidentReport** entity and **ReportEntry** entity and the following mapping is straight forward

```
@Entity
public class ReportEntry {

...
    @JoinColumn(name = "incident_report", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private IncidentReport incidentReport;

    private int type; // 0,1,2

    ...
} 


@Entity
public class IncidentReport {
    ...    

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "incidentReport")
    private Collection<ReportEntry> reportEntryCollection;


    ...    
}
```

But ideally I would like to have 3 different collection( one for each type of Report Entry)  of **ReportEntry**  in the **IncidentReport**  class.

Is there a way to map the collection based on 2 keys, say **incidentReport** and value of **type** ?

Something like this:

```
@Entity
public class IncidentReport {
    ...    

    // Type 0
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "incidentReport", 
                                          mappedBy = "type = 0" )
    private Collection<ReportEntry> reportEntryCollection1;

    // Type 1
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "incidentReport" 
                                          mappedBy = "type = 1" )
    private Collection<ReportEntry> reportEntryCollection1;

    // Type 2
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "incidentReport" 
                                          mappedBy = "type = 2" )
    private Collection<ReportEntry> reportEntryCollection1;


    ...    
}
```

Is there a way to do that ? My back plan is to add another entity to map these separately.  Which is a really poor way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is type parameter, i would recommend you define 3 different entities based on that parameter

```
@Entity
public class Type1ReportEntry extends ReportEntry{}

@Entity
public class Type2ReportEntry extends ReportEntry{}

@Entity
public class Type3ReportEntry extends ReportEntry{}
```

Because as far as @OneToMany mapping is concerned, you wont be able to accomplish what you want.

You dont need to define any namedquery:

assume you already have EntityManager resource injected into your session beans, or created it from EntityManagerFactory

```
 public ReportEntry getReportEntry(Class<? extends ReportEntry> reportType){
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().
            createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(reportType));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
  }
```

Comment: How should I restrict the rows based on the value of Type. Should I use a named query and add the type=1 in the WHERE clause ?

Comment: If I have to get all the ReportEntry  objects having type value = 1. Then how should I form the entity.